# what database triggers have been executed in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, logging

Right now I am using a middleware to log all the queries executed in Laravel through [query log](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#query-logging). My question is if it is possible to also log the actions occurred by database triggers.

For example, when deleting a model with onDelete cascade. Query log only shows the delete query but not the children queries.

Comment: cascade is handled by mysql, these queries happen 'in the background'/'outside of the scope of laravel', if you want to track them in laravel i would suggest removing the automatic trigger, and deleting its children on the `::deleting()` event of their parents.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers and cascade deleting is out side the scope of Laravel these are only handled by MySql.

If you dont remove the triggers and Cascade you can still log the queries.

E.G

In your Model if you want to delete the child row or associated rows you can use

```
protected $cascadeDeletes = ['relation', 'relation2'];
```

The `$cascadeDeletes` delete will delete the whole related model too. and these queries will be logged by laravel Query Logger.

Hope this helps